# i wanted all checkboxes should be unchecked after submmiting form and for another form it should be unchecked react

Tags: arrays, reactjs, checkbox

This event is used to get only check values. how can I uncheck all checkboxes after firing this event?

```
okShippingTemplate = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = [];
    this.state.DomesticRegion.map((itm, index) => {
      if (itm.isChecked == true) {
        return data.push(itm.value);
      }
    });
    let domesticArray = [...this.state.domesticArray];
    domesticArray.push(data);
    this.setState({

      modal: !this.state.modal,
      showCheck: true,
      domesticArray: domesticArray,
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below:-

```
okShippingTemplate = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = [];
    this.state.DomesticRegion.map((itm, index) => {
      if (itm.isChecked == true) {
        return data.push(itm.value);
      }
    });
    let domesticArray = [...this.state.domesticArray];
    domesticArray.push(data);

    // code to uncheck all 
    const domesticRegionArray = [...this.state.DomesticRegion];
    const unCheckedArray = domesticRegionArray.map(item => {
      item.isChecked = false;
      return item;
    });
   
    this.setState({

      modal: !this.state.modal,
      showCheck: true,
      domesticArray: domesticArray,
      DomesticRegion: unCheckedArray // set DomesticRegion array
    });
  };
```

Comment: we cant uncheck checkboxes at mentioned above function was my mine(okShippingTemplate) ??

Comment: I have merged both function in one. please check updated answer

Comment: If you find this answer useful then please upvote it so other people can find it more easily.

Comment: bro, i dont know why i have reached my limit to ask questions on stackoverflow but I have problem can you solve??

how can I push a checkbox value to an array which is by default checked ??

Comment: I am sorry but I did not get you. Can you please explain more?

Comment: what is issue in this one?

Comment: handleInputChangeDom = (event) => {
    const target = event.target;
    var value = target.value;
    const Address_type = this.state.Address_type;
     if (event.target.checked) {
      Address_type.push(event.target.value);
    } else {
      let index = Address_type.indexOf(event.target.value);
      Address_type.splice(index, 1);
    }
 this.setState({
      Address_type: Address_type,
    });
  };

look at the event ....i have checkboxes and  I want to push a checkbox to an array which is by default checked. how can I push by default checked value to an array ?

Comment: please let me know if you are not getting my point

Comment: So you have some checkbox which are checked but that value are not pushed into `Address_type` array and when you deselect them you are facing problem, right?

Comment: yes, but i have a checkbox which is by default checked then it should be pushed into Address_type array automatically because it checked by default .

how can I do this ??

Comment: You can do that by useEffect. In that you need to pushed all checkbox which are checked.

Comment: please check my questions i have recently uploaded on my stackover flow account.

my code is class based so I cant use useEffect